# Sequence of real numbers

Tags: number-theory

> The sequence $\left(\, a_{n} \,\right)$ of real numbers is defined as follows:
>   $$
> a_{1} = 1,\quad a_{2} = 2\quad\mbox{and}\quad
> a_{n} = 3a_{n - 1} - a_{n - 2}\,,\quad n \geq 3.$$
>   Prove that for
>   $\displaystyle{n \geq 3}$,
>   $\displaystyle{a_n =
> \left\lfloor\,{{a_{n - 1}^{2} \over a_{n - 2}}}\,\right\rfloor + 1}$, where $\left\lfloor\, x\, \right\rfloor$ denotes the integer $p$ such that
>   $p \leq x < p+1$.

I tried relating this to the Fibonacci sequence but it didn't work. Is there an easier way or would induction be the best way ?.

Comment: http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C5%2C13%2C34&language=english&go=Search Oeis comes in handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$a_n=F_{2n-1}$$ Where $F_{n}$ denotes the $n$th Fibonacci number.
This can be proved by mathematical induction, as $$F_{2n+1}=F_{2n}+F_{2n-1}=2F_{2n-1}+F_{2n-2}=3F_{2n-1}-F_{2n-3}$$
Now use that $$a_{n}^2=a_{n+1}a_{n-1}-1$$ Which Follows from [Catalan's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities).
So we have that $$\left[\frac{a_{n}^2}{a_{n-1}}\right]+1=\left[\frac{a_{n+1}a_{n-1}-1}{a_{n-1}}\right]+1=a_{n+1}$$

We are done.

Comment: How does this help solve the question?

Comment: @user19405892 Connection to the Lucas Numbers.

Comment: How is it related?

Comment: @user19405892 Nevermind, I found a shorter solution. I shall post it.

Comment: I think you mean $a_n^2 = a_{n+1}a_{n-1}+1$.

Comment: @user19405892 Catalan's Identity suggests that $$F_{2n+1}=F_{2n-1}F_{2n+3}+(-1)^{2n+1-2}F_{2}^2=F_{2n-1}F_{2n+3}-1$$

Comment: @user19405892 Did you understand my answer?